# Related field id in POST request in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating the object with just only related field `id`. I have searched a lot but couldn't get the answer. Here is my code

**models.py:**

```
class Resturant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)

class Menu(models.Model):
    resturant_id = models.OneToOneField(Resturant, related_name='resturant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resturant_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'resturant_id']
```

**views.py:**

```
class CreateMenuAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = MenuSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am getting this error while sending `{ "resturant_id": 2 }` in POST request.

```
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, 2018-04-02 09:36:43.261849+00, null).
The above exception (null value in column "resturant_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: share more  error trackback ?

Comment: see edited post

Answer (score 4):

you can override method create for find Restaurant object or create if not exist. and only edit serializer.

serializer.py

```
  class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      resturant_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

      class Meta:
          model = Menu
          fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'resturant_id']

      def create(self, validated_data):
        id_param = validated_data.pop('resturant_id')
        resturant = Resturant.objects.get_or_create(id=id_param)[0]
        menu = Menu.objtects.create(resturant_id=resturant.id)
        return menu
```

if not work you can delete this line:

```
resturant_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
returant_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

Could you try giving read_only=False

Could you check the spelling, 
returant_id is used in serializers field,'s' is missing.
'resturant_id' is used in fields list

Comment: Could you check the spelling, returant_id is used in meta,'s' is missing. 'resturant_id' is used in fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a model serializer and have overridden 'returant_id'.

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    returant_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Resturant.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the serializer to

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resturant_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'resturant_id']
```

if `read_only=True` then it will not write into database.

Comment: share the data that you are sending in the request